2 subdomains 2 NGINX servers twice HTTPS
I'm starting with nginx.
I'm trying to have two nginx servers in my LAN. One Odoo, one passbolt.
Like this :
LAN Nginx 2 Servers 2 subdomains
I have an Odoo server, with Let's Encrypt certificate working perfectly.
odoo.domain.com, 192.168.1.159, NAT redirection, with this nginx conf:
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

# http -> https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name odoo.domain.fr;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name odoo.domain.fr;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.domain.fr/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/odoo.domain.fr/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect websocket requests to odoo gevent port
  location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
   }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
  }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
}

I started to install a passbolt server, and it need 443 https enforce with Let's Encrypt certificate. On passbolt.domain.com, 192.168.1.160, if I'm modifying the NAT redirection to the passbolt server IP in the router, it works perfectly too.
With this nginx conf:
#
#  Passbolt.conf - Nginx configuration file to run the Passbolt software.
#

server {

  # Managed by Passbolt
  server_name passbolt.domain.fr;

  client_body_buffer_size     100K;
  client_header_buffer_size   1K;
  client_max_body_size        5M;

  client_body_timeout   10;
  client_header_timeout 10;
  keepalive_timeout     5 5;
  send_timeout          10;

  root /usr/share/php/passbolt/webroot;
  index index.php;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/passbolt-error.log info;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/passbolt-access.log;

  # Managed by Passbolt
  # include __PASSBOLT_SSL__

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files                $uri =404;
    include                  fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass             unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index            index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.+)$;
    fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param            SERVER_NAME $http_host;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE  "upload_max_filesize=5M \n post_max_size=5M";
  }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/passbolt.domain.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/passbolt.domain.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = passbolt.domain.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name passbolt.domain.fr;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

I don't know how to redirect requests for "passbolt.domain.fr" to the other nginx server.
What nginx server have to manage certificate for the "passbolt.domain.fr" ? It's the odoo one ?
Can anyone help me?
I've tried to redirect with a new upstream on the Odoo nginx, and redirect but certificate and SSL error still occur, or the odoo nginx stoppped to work.
